How to define the method signature in a subclass
I'm implementing a repository pattern as an excercise on typing.
I have a couple of unrelated SQLAlchemy models:
class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[primary_key] = mapped_column(init=False)

default_string = Annotated[str, mapped_column(String(100))]

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    name: Mapped[default_string]

class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    value: Mapped[default_string]
    location: Mapped[default_string]

I want to create a Repository for each to have a uniform way to interact and query, and I want to use typing to hint the usage.
Say:
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

class Repository(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[T]):
        self.db = SessionLocal()
        self.model = model

    def list(self, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
        return self.db.query(self.model).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()

So I use them as:
class SampleRepository(Repository[Sample]):
    def get_by_name(self, name: str) -> list[Sample]:
        return self.model.query.filter(name=name).all()

repository = SampleRepository(Sample)

Now, thing is, on repository.create(), which is a quite convulted piece of logic, I'd need to have different signatures for the different model arguments. I thought of using dict unpacking in this case
class Repository(ABC, Generic[T]):
    ...
    def create(self, **data) -> T:
        instance = self.model(**data)
        self.db.add(instance)
        self.db.commit()
        self.db.refresh(instance)
        return instance

But If I try to overload this method in the SampleRepository as such:
class SampleRepository(Repository[Sample]):
    def create(self, name: str) -> Sample:
        return super().create(
                name=name,
        )

This breaks as the signature of "create" incompatible with supertype "Repository".
Is there a way to achieve this? or I'm asking too much to the type system?

I can think of one solution for this problem, but it does not play well with type checkers in general: it is only supported (correctly) by Pyright 1.1.387, which will come out on Wednesday this week (October 30, 2024).
For simplicity, let's get rid of the hierarchy of SQLAlchemy models and replace them with a single dataclass. Also, the explanation will use PEP 695 syntax for its conciseness. Both of these shouldn't affect the solution.
First, we have our model:
@dataclass
class Sample:
    value: str
    location: str

As for Repository, we declare it to be generic over T. SampleRepository thus can keep being what it currently is.
class Repository[T](ABC):
    model: type[T]
    def __init__(self, model: type[T]) -> None: ...

class SampleRepository(Repository[Sample]): ...

Now comes the hard part: .create(). Your current code does not work because Repository.create() accepts any and all keyword arguments via **data, whereas SampleRepository.create() only accepts name: str. This violates the Liskov substitution principle.
Despite its current name and semantic meaning, **data is meant to capture the parameters to self.model. This means we will need to make it a type parameter as well.
But to which generic? Definitely not Repository; you won't be able to specify a precise type when declaring SampleRepository:
class Repository[**P, T]:
    model: Callable[P, T]  # So that the type checker know how to infer P.
    def __init__(self, model: Callable[P, T]) -> None: ...
    def create(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...

class SampleRepository(Repository[[str, str], Sample]): ...
#                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ Parameter names are lost!

This leaves one possible choice: .create() itself.
class Repository[T]:
    model: type[T]
    def create[**P](self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...

Since functions have yet to be subscriptable, this seemingly leads to the same problem, if not worse, as the type checker now has no clue whatsoever to figure out what P refers to.
...or does it?
class HasModel[**P, T](Protocol):
    model: Callable[P, T]

class Repository[T]:
    model: type[T]
    def create[**P](self: HasModel[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...
#                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

As you can see, the protocol HasModel, whose type parameters do not need to be declared explicitly, allows us to transform type[T] to Callable[P, T].
One downside, though: Inside .create(), self will no longer have access to other attributes of Repository. This can be overcome either by copying the attributes over to HasModel, or by casting:
class Repository[T]:
    model: type[T]
    def create[**P](self: HasModel[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        self.db                       # error: HasModel[P, T] has no attribute "db"
        cast(Repository[T], self).db  # fine

To sum it up:
(old syntax)
@dataclass
class Sample:
    value: str
    location: str

class HasModel[**P, T](Protocol):
    model: Callable[P, T]

class Repository[T]:
    model: type[T]
    def __init__(self, model: type[T]) -> None: ...
    def create[**P](self: HasModel[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...

class SampleRepository(Repository[Sample]):
    def __init__(self) -> None: ...

reveal_type(SampleRepository.create)  # (value: str, location: str) -> Sample

I wasn't sure of this solution myself, so I asked Pyright's maintainers if it should work. To quote the reply:

It's a clever pattern — one that pushes the boundaries of the type system and veers into territory that is not well defined currently in the typing spec.

So there you go: A solution that has yet to work with any type checkers. Nevertheless, it has a sound foundation (type[T] is assignable to Callable[P, T]). It's entirely up to you to choose whether you want to use it.

Thanks for the detailed answer!.
I'd think I'm not ready to push the boundaries of the type system for the time being XD.
What would a simplier solution to this look like? Should I just accept an single argument in my create? something like a dto?

@tutuca If I could think of a simpler solution, I would have posted that instead. Ultimately, your design choices lie with you; I clearly don't know your code as good as you do, and thus can't provide you with what is best for your situation, only what you might consider.

Fair enough :) I'll give it a couple of twists and see if I can make it pass without ignoring typing on this method. Really appreciate your input and the time you put in the answer. Have a great day!
